# Convert Multi Index back to columns after pivot a table in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to pivot a table with multiple columns.

Dataframe

```
 a       b       c      d

id_1   loc_1   sale_1  1
id_1   loc_1   sale_2  2
id_2   loc_2   sale_1  3
id_2   loc_2   sale_2  4
```

I applied the following logic

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['a', 'b'], columns='c', values='d')
```

I got the following output

```
                    sale_1  sale_2
('id_1', 'loc_1')      1      2
('id_2', 'loc_2')      3      4
```

but i want it as

```
 a       b     sale_1  sale_2
id_1   loc_1      1      2
id_2   loc_2      3      4
```

I tried changing the logic to

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['a', 'b'], columns='c', values='d').reset_index()
```

but i am facing an error of

```
TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not 
           already an existing category
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get that output with `pandas 0.24.0`

Comment: Your actual data might be a lot different from the sample data.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the pivoted dataframe has categorical columns. Reset that:

```
new_df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['a', 'b'], columns='c', values='d')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.categories

new_df.reset_index()
```

Return:

```
    a       b       sale_1  sale_2
0   id_1    loc_1   1       2
1   id_2    loc_2   3       4
```

Comment: Thank You so much, It works! I haven't  that realized it was getting caused by the categorical variable